# Using dynamic-dynamodb library I get "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, python-2.6

After I pulled dynamic-dynamodb via git and made my changes to `example-dynamic-dynamodb.conf` and install the `requirements.txt`,
**I am trying to run/start dynamic-dynamodb**

I am running on AWS EC2

- OS: ubuntu 14.04
- `python --version` Python 2.6.9
- `pip --version` pip 7.1.2 from `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages` (python 2.6)

---

```
$>cd dynamic-dynamodb

    $>ls
    build  cloudformation-templates  dist  docs  dynamic_dynamodb  dynamic-dynamodb  dynamic_dynamodb.egg-info  example-dynamic-dynamodb.conf  LICENSE  Makefile  MANIFEST  MANIFEST.in  README  README.md  requirements.txt  setup.py

    $>./dynamic-dynamodb start

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./dynamic-dynamodb", line 22, in <module>
    import dynamic_dynamodb
  File "/root/dynamic-dynamodb/dynamic_dynamodb/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from dynamic_dynamodb.aws import dynamodb
  File "/root/dynamic-dynamodb/dynamic_dynamodb/aws/dynamodb.py", line 12, in <module>
    from dynamic_dynamodb.log_handler import LOGGER as logger
  File "/root/dynamic-dynamodb/dynamic_dynamodb/log_handler.py", line 26, in <module>
    import config_handler
  File "/root/dynamic-dynamodb/dynamic_dynamodb/config_handler.py", line 5, in <module>
    CONFIGURATION = config.get_configuration()
  File "/root/dynamic-dynamodb/dynamic_dynamodb/config/__init__.py", line 155, in get_configuration
    'tables': ordereddict()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Is this the right way to start `dynamic-dynamodb` service?
Dose any one have an advice?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in dynamic-dynamodb.

In `dynamic_dynamodb/config/config_file_parser.py` and `dynamic_dynamodb/config/__init__.py`, there is code like:

```
try:
    from collections import OrderedDict as ordereddict
except ImportError:
    import ordereddict
```

`ImportError` is caught when you're using a version lower than 2.7, and `collections.OrderedDict` doesn't exist. But doing just `import ordereddict` seems like a logical error; you want `ordereddict` to point to the `OrderedDict` class, not the module that contains the OrderedDict class.

First, I suggest upgrading to 2.7 or higher, where this is no longer a problem.

Second, If you can't do that, I suggest changing the lines in both of those files to

```
try:
    from collections import OrderedDict as ordereddict
except ImportError:
    from ordereddict import OrderedDict as ordereddict
```

Third, if that doesn't work, I suggest filing a bug on the github page, and hopefully the author will issue a fix. (actually, you should probably do this regardless of whether the previous two approaches succeed)

Comment: Changing  the lines in both of those files to
try:
    from collections import OrderedDict as ordereddict
except ImportError:
    from ordereddict import OrderedDict as ordereddict
fixed the problem, Thanks. Yeah i will because its the 2nd bug i find but not able to fix :) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it looks like this is all due to the current t1.micro instance does not come updated with Python 2.7, and pip cannot install dynamic-dynamodb package without it. So I tried to update all in sequence and it worked for me, I have tried a couple times and missing any of these steps or out of order would not work.

```
sudo yum update
sudo update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python2.7
sudo easy_install pip
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install -U dynamic-dynamodb
```